# How to compare a file on 2 different git remotes

Tags: git

I want to compare a file (main_controller.rb) on 2 different remotes (namely, production and staging) since I got different behavior on production and staging.

I believe the code (i.e. the file) is the same, but just wanted to be sure.  But I can't figure out how to do this comparison in git.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have both remotes set up in the same repo? I'll assume you do, and that they're called `production` and `staging`. There is a way to refer to a file in a specific commit/tree, and the syntax is `treeish:path/to/file`. You should be able to use this with `git diff` to say something like

```
git diff production:path/to/file staging:path/to/file
```